# How do I rotate values in a cvMat?

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I am making a steerable derivative line filter. I want to be able to rotate it by an arbitrary angle. The desired situation will be the following:

```
cvMat myMat;
```

> ```
> contains:
> 0, 0, 0
> 0, 0, 1
> 0, 0, 0
> ```

```
float angle = radians(45);
UnknownRotateMethod(myMat, angle);
```

> ```
> myMat desired result:
> 0, 0, 0
> 0, 0, 0
> 0, 0, 1 
> (or similar due to discretization and aliasing)
> ```

Note I am using the C OpenCV API.

Edit: even though my example shows it, I would like to spell out that I want the rotation to be done on an axis point different from the (0,0). In this example I want the pivot to be at the center point of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
cv2DRotationMatrix(pivot,angleDegrees,scale,outRotationMat);
cvWarpAffine(myMat,myMat,outRotationMat);
```